# Proper way of evaluating test tools

Tags: automated-testing, tools

Im currently trying to evaluate two different test tools (SpecExplorer vs Quviq Quickcheck) with regards to how many bugs they find in my code. The plan i have is to insert some faults in my code and evaluate how long it takes the tools to find the faults and how many they find. I want the method to be easy and manual but still be a valid method. I have been looking into fault injection but to my understanding fault injection is an automatic process requiring advanved tools.

So my question is what are well estamblished methods for compairing testing tools?

Answer (score 1):

There are no well-established methods for comparing test tools.  You need to evaluate them based on your own requirements.  If you don't know what your requirements are, try using both tools and write down what you learn.  Or if one tool is free and the other costs money, try the free tool first.